# jQuery change value of input and display it as text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm struggling with the following problem. I have input text element. I want a user to enter something there and then his value appears as a normal text (the input should disappear).

I searched for a few solutions but nothing worked for me. What I tried (whatever function I provide, I get no results, what should I provide to get the effect I described above and how to make it happen?):

```
$('input.modified').on('input', function(){
        (this).append('<p>some</p>');
});
```

OR

```
$("input.modified").bind("propertychange change keyup paste input", function(){
    $(this).append("<p>dgdgd</p>");
});
```

OR

```
$("input.modified").change(function(){
           $(this).css("visibility","hidden");
 }); //end change function
```

How to make functions like .on() or .change() work with my code?

---

thanks for all the answer, but I can't move your examples to my code :(

Please verify this fiddle what I'm missing:

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/w6242/][1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/PTV4Z/)**

**HTML**:

```
<input class="modified" type="text"/>
<p></p>
```

---

**JS**:

```
$("input.modified").change(function(){
           $('p').html($(this).val());
           $(this).css("visibility","hidden");
});
```

Comment: shaunakde, thx for the reply. It works perfectly on the fiddle but I can't get it to work in my script. When I give some text and click outside the input it still does nothing :(

Comment: shaunakde, here is my fiddle, please check what is missing. It doesn't work there neither:  http://jsfiddle.net/w6242/

Comment: you have not selected jquery version. Right top corner : **Frameworks and Extensions**.  Your fiddle needs jQuery. **[Updated Version](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/w6242/1/)**

Comment: It's 2.1.1, but is not listed there

Comment: O.K. when I select some versions of jQuery it works fine. But I still don't understand why can't I run it locally on my computer. The version I have is jQuery 2.1.1

Comment: Check this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/w6242/4/)** I have attached 2.1.1.

Comment: The code without this additional code works perfect so the path is O.K. I added  console.log('a');  after $(this).css("visibility","hidden");  and it didn't show anything

Comment: O.K. the problem is solved. My input element is added dynamically so the function didn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

check this

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/madhust/wMqv8/1/)

```
$("#in").focusout(function(e){
$("span").html(($("#in").val()));
           $(this).hide();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a  fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/keypaul/NsWC5/5/

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <input type="text" id="writer" />
    <a href="#" id="submit">send</a>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$("#submit").click(function(e){
    var txt = $("#writer").val();
    $("#writer").fadeOut(400);
    $("#submit").fadeOut(400, function(){
        $("#wrapper").append('<div id="text">' + txt + '</div>').hide().fadeIn(600);
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

If you need to do that with onther event (instead of a click submit) you can use onchange or focusout applied to your input element

Answer (score 0):

At its simplest, assuming you *really* want to replace the `input`:

```
$('#demo').on('keyup', function(e){
    if (e.which === 13) {
        var p = $('<p />', {
            text : this.value
        });
        $(this).replaceWith(p);
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2Letu/).

Or, to insert an adjacent element and simply hide the `input`:

```
$('#demo').on('keyup', function(e){
    if (e.which === 13) {
        var span = $('<span />', {
            text : this.value
        });
        $(this).hide().after(span);
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2Letu/1/).

The above jQuery works with the following demonstrative HTML:

```
<input id="demo" type="text" />
```

References:

- [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/).
- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/).